# How do you match a string that precedes and/or succeeds a string or character that matches a given pattern?

Tags: regex

I couldn't find a general question on the Internet, so I figured I'd ask it here.
What syntax would I use to match a string that precedes another string or character that matches a given pattern.

**Example**
Suppose I have a string like this:

```
Lorem ipsum: dolor sit amet; consectator:
```

What regex would return "`Lorem ipsum`" and "`Lorem ipsum: dolor sit amet; consectator`" because they precede a `:`?

What regex would return "`dolor sit amet; consectator:`" because they succeed a `:`?
Etc.

Answer (score 1):

- `^.+?(?=:)` matches `Lorem ipsum`
- `^.+(?=:)` matches `Lorem ipsum: dolor sit amet; consectator`
- `(?<=:).+` matches `dolor sit amet; consectator:`

Have a play with explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/PIVvjB/1)

Comment: Oh regex, you're so beautiful yet confusing. No wonder people hate you.

Comment: @moonman239: ;-)

Comment: After some consideration, I've decided to withdraw my acceptance of your answer for the following reason: This question calls for a general answer that can be applied to any string, not just the example string, and your answer is too specific.

Comment: @moonman239: Sorry, I don't get you; my answer works for any kind of string, just replace `:` with any string and it will work. If this is  not what you want, edit your question and  add more test cases.

Comment: True, but you didn't say that in the answer.